# Copy paste is not triggering cell renderer for all the rows

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have implemented ag-grid in angular application.
ag-grid version: 21.0.0
angular version: 6

I am having a grid, which has 108 columns and 200 rows.

Around 50 of those columns are having separate cell renderers.

I am copying certain column values from a cell and pasting them into a column for all the rows.
On processCellFromClipboard event, I expected all the rows refresh method will be triggered. But it didn't happen.

But the cell renderer is refreshed only for the rows which are visible in the DOM at that particular time. Only for 20 rows cell renderer is getting triggered. For others it is not getting triggered.

Is there any option to refresh/re-render for all the rows which are not visible by that time?

Answer (score 1):

agGrid has a `rowBuffer` attribute that handles the number of rows that the grid can actually interact with at a time.

If you are using pagination you can easily set it to the current page size, otherwise set it to the number you want or the one that you display at a time.

[*If that didn't help please post more code and ping me*]